# How can I tell if Bitlocker is activated with Python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-10, bitlocker

I'm devellopping a Python app that would automatically collect general information about a windows (8 or 10) system, and I would like to add information about Bitlocker.

I would like to know if there is way to tell if Bitlocker is activated without using the manual command 'manage-bde -status'. I still can read the output of 'manage-bde status' but if it changes after an update, my process will not work anymore.

So is there an other way to know it, per exemple by reading a value in a file, or something like this ?

edit : I don't want to use a solution like "os.system('manage-bde -status')" because of the output that could change after bitlocker updates.

Comment: Calling `os.system('manage-bde -status')` is not an option?

Comment: This is what I meant with "I still can read the output of 'manage-bde status'", I would like an other option if it's possible.